# Decrease horizontal space in moderncv's cvdoubleitem

Tags: spacing, moderncv

When labels are too small, the `\cvdoubleitem` macro in moderncv creates way too much space between the first description and the second label:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{}
\familyname{}

\begin{document}
\section{Cool Stuff}
\cvdoubleitem{$15\times$}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.}{$6\times$}{Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\end{document}
```

I like to decrease the yellow space by increasing the description columns.

Thank you for any hints how to achieve this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

> With `moderncv` v2.0, the length `\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth` has been
>   replaced by `\doubleitemcolumnwidth`, so all the occurrences of the
>   former have to be replaced with the latter name.

The above update was found and copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219637/87996).

### Original answer (older versions of `moderncv`)

That space is used for the hints column. In the following code I reduced the length used for that `minipage` to half its original value and distributed the remaining space in the two `minipage`s used for the descriptions:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{}
\familyname{}

\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth+0.25\hintscolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth+0.25\hintscolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Cool Stuff}
\cvdoubleitem{$15\times$}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.}{$6\times$}{Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\end{document}
```

For comparison, an image with the default widths:

[image]

the same document with the modification suggested:

[image]

Notice that now the space reserved for the third mandatory argument is half than it was before.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, looks really good :-)

However, ìt seems we need to wrap the macro's content in `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, because `\addtolength` would keep adding up on each call of `\cvdoubleitem`.

Comment: @MarcusBitzl yes, my bad. Sorry. I've fixed the code now without `\addtolength`.