# Modern CV \cvitem adjust

Tags: moderncv

Here is an example with modern cv :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@smith.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Skills}

\cvdoubleitem{AAAA}{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}{CCCC}{DDDDDDD}
\cvdoubleitem{EEEE}{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}{GGGG}{HHHHH}

\end{document}
```

What I don't manage to do is :

- to either raise or go back down "GGGG" item position and its content "HHHH". I don't know where to add \vspace or similar command to do that.
- add an additional item below previous 4 items and that would be centered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, the length `\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth` has been replaced by `\doubleitemcolumnwidth`, so all the occurrences of the former have to be replaced with the latter name.

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

Although I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, here it is.

About your first request, we can adjust the definition of `\cvdoubleitem`

```
\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
   \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}\raggedright\hintstyle{#5}\end{minipage}}}
```

so you can use something like

```
\\[<skip>]
```

in the last two arguments to raise them up and down.

For example, use

```
\\[\baselineskip]
```

to raise them down 2 lines and

```
\\[-3\baselineskip]
```

to raise them up 2 lines.

In regards of your second request, we can define a new command `\cvtripleitem`

```
\newcommand*{\cvtripleitem}[6][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
   \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}\raggedright\hintstyle{#5}\end{minipage}}%
   \par\noindent%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\centering#6\end{minipage}}
```

which takes one more argument that will be centered below the entry line.

The following MWE shows you how to use them.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
   \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}\raggedright\hintstyle{#5}\end{minipage}}}

\newcommand*{\cvtripleitem}[6][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
   \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}\raggedright\hintstyle{#5}\end{minipage}}%
   \par\noindent%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\centering#6\end{minipage}}


\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@smith.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Skills}

\cvdoubleitem{AAAA}{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}{CCCC}{DDDDDDD}
\cvdoubleitem{EEEE}{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}{\\[\baselineskip]GGGG}{\\[\baselineskip]HHHHH}

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}

\cvdoubleitem{EEEE}{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}{\\[-3\baselineskip]GGGG}{\\[-3\baselineskip]HHHHH}
\cvtripleitem{JJJJ}{KKKKKKKKKKKKKKK}{LLLL}{MMMMMMM}{centered line}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi karkoeller, thanks a lot, it is absolutely brilliant. Too bad I can't udnerstand anything myself yet. Regarding double item modification it is perfect. Rergarding triple item version, I would need "centered line" to have same structure than any item. I know I have to modify previous structure. I tried but I dont understand.

Comment: @abel Simply you have to give one more argument to `\cvtripleitem` respect to `\cvdoubleitem` which is the contents to be centered.