# Change moderncv cvdoubleitem style

Tags: moderncv

I tried editing the `\cvdoubleitem` in the class `moderncv`, style `banking`. I wanted to boldface the categories. I tried the following but it gives a very weird alignment when I do so, although boldfacing the text correctly.

```
\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.5em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{\bfseries#2}{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
        \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{\bfseries#4}\end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}
```

However, this produces, on 2 double items (4 items),
[image: Screw up of \cvdoubleitem]

I thought editing the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159862/decrease-horizontal-space-in-moderncvs-cvdoubleitem) might help but that original code itself gave me an error so I didn't try.

An MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{ieujrghieu}{wirjufhiuryg}

\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.5em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{\bfseries#2}{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
        \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{\bfseries#4}\end{minipage}%
        \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
    \cvdoubleitem{TTTTTTT}{doiuehneiuhrigbn3ghbn iurh fg3iuh gi3uh giu43ygh iu3 ghiu3rg3iu}{GGGGGGGGGG}{eihg uegh iuh 39uf h23 948h f924 fu4g fiuf 2iuf g4iuf g}
    \cvdoubleitem{PPPPPPPPP}{rusfhvioehr iughe r}{MMMMMM}{3iurgh re3uygh 3eur}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those (TTTTTT and PPPPPP) are bold by default. Anyway, you can change their appearance  by redefining `hintfont`.

Comment: Your redefinition of `cvdoubleitem`  is calling `cvitem`. That is far from what the template is supposed to do and leads to the weird alignment.

Comment: Oh OK there was another code which was un-bolding this. Thanks. I copied the redefinition from the main body .sty files. It seemed to call cvitem to define cvdoubleitem so I did.

Comment: Maybe you are using a modified version? That's why i asked for a link to the template. People aren't really treating other peoples copyright well, changing files again and again. Makes life of a helper a nightmare. Please add the link to the question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146770/classic-title-and-banking-body-style-mixed-moderncv

I used the first answer here to edit my header.

The \renewcommand*{\hintfont}{} line screwed it up.

Comment: The whole template got changed in the meantime, making older solutions obsolete. Still, i don't see any redefinition of `cvdoubleitem`  there.

Comment: The `\cvdoubleitem` edit was from the moderncvbodyi in the latest version on CTAN, which is what I am using, the


`
\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}
`

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of class `moderncv` 2.0.0 for style `banking` you will find the correct definition of command `\cvdoubleitem` in file `moderncvbodyiii.sty`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\hintstyle{#2}: #3\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#4}: }#5\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Command `\hintstyle` defined that text `#2` or `#4` has to be printed bold.
It is defined in the class as `\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}` 
and `\hintfont` is defined as `\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\bfseries}`

To get rid of printing bold you can define an own new command `\mycvdoubleitem` and delete there the both commands `\hintstyle{}`. Now you can change `\mycvdoubleitem` for your needs.

The following MWE shows the difference of commands `\cvdoubleitem` and `\mycvdoubleitem`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{ieujrghieu}{wirjufhiuryg}


\newcommand*{\mycvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#2: #3\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4: }#5\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}


\begin{document}
  \cvdoubleitem{1TTTTTTT}{2doiuehneiuhrigbn3ghbn iurh fg3iuh gi3uh 
    giu43ygh iu3 ghiu3rg3iu}{3GGGGGGGGGG}{4eihg uegh iuh 39uf h23 948h 
    f924 fu4g fiuf 2iuf g4iuf g}
  \cvdoubleitem{1PPPPPPPPP}{2rusfhvioehr iughe r}{3MMMMMM}{43iurgh 
    re3uygh 3eur}

  \mycvdoubleitem{1TTTTTTT}{2doiuehneiuhrigbn3ghbn iurh fg3iuh gi3uh 
    giu43ygh iu3 ghiu3rg3iu}{3GGGGGGGGGG}{4eihg uegh iuh 39uf h23 948h 
    f924 fu4g fiuf 2iuf g4iuf g}
  \mycvdoubleitem{1PPPPPPPPP}{2rusfhvioehr iughe r}{3MMMMMM}{43iurgh 
    re3uygh 3eur}

\end{document}
```

with the result

[image: resulting pdf]